# RestKit path pattern for comma separated dynamic arguments

Tags: ios, iphone, rest, restkit

I am using RestKit, i have send a single GET request to get a bulk data to a URL like this

```
api/exemptions?ids=203,1985,21855
```

What path pattern can be set for this in RestKit response descriptor?

I know for predefined number of dynamic argument we can use something like this `@"/api/sms/confirmation/:arg1/:arg2"`

but above mentioned case is new for me.

**EDIT**

I found that parameter argument in

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:path parameters:nil
```

will do the job, but it requires a dictionary so i am giving it an example dictionary `NSDictionary *args = @{ @"ids" : @[@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4"] };`

when executed this encoded url is generated

http://../api/exemptions?&ids%5B%5D=1&ids%5B%5D=2&ids%5B%5D=3&ids%5B%5D=4

"ids" key is repeating, what is going wrong here.

**EDIT # 2**

URL encoding problem is solved, but the main problem still persists, path pattern is not matching on response, I am using this path pattern currently

```
pathPattern:@"/api/exemptions?&ids"
```

for this url /api/exemptions?ids=203,1985,21855

i have also tried `pathPattern:@"/api/exemptions?&ids="`

Please help, This is becoming huge pain.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your sample code and response, have you tried:

```
NSDictionary *args = @{ @"ids": [@[@"1", @"2"] componentsJoinedByString: @","] };
```

This looks like it would encode with the desired value, since the joining leads to a dictionary value of `@{ @"ids": @"1,2" }`.

Comment: @Umair: If it solved the problem for you, then please accept my answer (click the checkmark) so that others can see that quickly without having to review comments. :)